# Meaning of "ne" in "In meinem Keller liegt ne Leiche"

Tags: meaning, particle

Does the particle *ne* in "In meinem Keller liegt ne Leiche" mean something or is it just an empty word for the poetic reasons (I've heard this line in the song)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case 'ne is short for **ei**ne, i.e. the indefinite article.

Comment: Oooh, beautiful. Das macht Sinn.

Comment: "ne Leiche" is spelled with apostrophe ('ne Leiche) to show that a syllable was dropped. It is spoken language only.

Comment: @rogermue Are there other colloquial shortening for the German articles?

Comment: In spoken language influenced by dialect das can become des, and ein can become ä (a weak e as English a).

Comment: If you leave out various dialect pronunciations, I can only think of ein => 'n and das = 's.